# Could we call postrgesql stored procedure like sqlserver exec with parameters names?

Tags: postgresql

Could we call postrgesql stored procedure like sqlserver exec with parameters names?

sqlserrver exec sp sample

```
exec procName 
    @parameter_1_Name = 'parameter_1_Value', 
    @parameter_2_name = 'parameter_2_value',
    @parameter_z_name = 'parameter_z_value'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres uses the SQL standard notation to provide parameters based on their names:

```
call the_proc(param_1 => 'one', param_3 => 'three', param_2 => 'two');
```

For more details [see the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-calling-funcs.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CALLING-FUNCS-NAMED)